# Minimal size of a proper class

Tags: set-theory

Assume ZFC consistent. Let $\mathcal c$ be some infinite cardinality and $\mathfrak F$ a family of models of ZFC of cardinality $\mathcal c$.

Let $\mathcal S = \left\{ \left\{ \{ x | x \in_{\mathcal M} C \} | C \textbf{ is proper class in } \mathcal M \right\} | \mathcal M \in \mathfrak F \right\}$

So $\mathcal S$ is a collection of sets that are a proper class of some ZFC model with cardinality $\mathcal c$.

Can anything be said about the minimal cardinality of the elements of $\mathcal{S}$? Is it necessarily $\mathcal c$ or can it be smaller?

Comment: For a model of ZFC, what does it mean to "be a proper class in it"? Are you speaking about all metalevel-subsets of the model's carrier set that are not sets in that model, or all first-order definable collections that are not sets, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Taneli Huuskonen says, if $M$ is a model of ZFC then (externally) there is a bijection between $M$ and $Ord^M$. The proof is as follows.

Since $M$ is a model of ZFC, $M$ thinks that every set in $M$ is well-orderable. This means that for every $m\in M$, the set $\{a\in M: a\in^M m\}$ injects into $Ord^M$.

Now consider the levels, in the sense of $M$, of the cumulative hierarchy; that is, the sets $(V_\alpha)^M$ for $\alpha\in Ord^M$. There are $\vert Ord^M\vert$-many of these, and each one has (external) cardinality $\le\vert Ord^M\vert$; so their union also has cardinality $\le \vert Ord^M\vert$ since $Ord^M$ is infinite. But this means that $\vert M\vert\le \vert Ord^M\vert$, and since $Ord^M\subseteq M$ this gives us $\vert M\vert=\vert Ord^M\vert$.

---

Now, some caveats with the same theme - that **definability is key**.

First of all, the class in question has to be definable in order for this to make any sense. If $X\subseteq M$ is not definable in $M$ (that is, not a class in $M$ in the usual sense of the word) then there is very little we can conclude about the cardinality of $X$ versus that of $M$. For example, we can have an uncountable model $M$ of ZFC where $Ord^M$ has (external) cofinality $\omega$; then there is a countable set of $M$-ordinals which has elements of arbitrarily large $M$-rank. Of course, such a set will not be definable in $M$.

Second, things get interesting once we talk about definable bijections/injections. The argument above shows that $\vert M\vert=\vert Ord^M\vert$ whenever $M$ is a model of ZFC. But we can also ask:

- If $M$ is a model of ZFC, is there necessarily a definable-in-$M$ class bijection between $Ord^M$ and $M$? *Exercise: it's enough to have a definable-in-$M$ injection from $M$ to $Ord^M$ - think about the Mostowski collapse ...*
- If $M$ is a model of ZFC, is there necessarily a definable-in-$M$ surjection from $Ord^M$ to $M$? *This would clearly be implied by a positive answer to the previous question.*

It turns out that the answer to even the second question may be "no." So once we restrict to *definable* comparisons, things can get much more interesting.

Comment: "If $X \subseteq M$ is not definable ..."

If $X$ is not definable, can it be a class? I read that classes are sub-collections of the universe of discourse that satisfy a certain formula. So the formula is the definition, isn't it?

"Of course, such a set will not be definable in $M$"

Is it definable outside of M? Or can we only say that such an M exists?

Comment: @Damian What I wrote may have been unclear; I meant to emphasize the role of definability in the notion of a class, not call $X$ a class. (Of course, $X$ may or may not be definable externally.)

Answer (score 2):

It is provable in ZFC that there is a definable surjection from any proper class $C$ onto the ordinals (collapse the class of ranks of the elements of $C$). OTOH, the cardinality of the ordinals of a model of ZFC is the same as the cardinality of the whole model. Thus, every proper class of a set model has the same cardinality as the model itself.

Comment: "It is provable in ZFC that there is a definable surjection from any proper class $C$ onto the ordinals"
Can you refer me to a proof please? I read that a proper class is a class whose elements have arbitrarily high rank. But the ranks can as well be arbitarily sparse, so I don't see it natually that they need to have a surjection onto the ordinals.

Comment: The order type of a proper class of ordinals is the same as the order type of them all.